# How to crop text without removing the div element, jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="ins"> test test test <div class="temp">123</div></div>
```

The script deletes the div with class "temp"

```
$('.ins').text(function(){
return $(this).text().slice(0,5);});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this piece of code, also keep it mind that this code will work only your given DOM structure:

```
$('.ins').html(function(){
    return $(this).text().slice(0,5) + '<div class="temp">'+ $(this).find('.temp').text() +'</div>';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the value inside `.temp` div and clear the content from the same div element. In here div's content assinged to a variable.

```js
var res = $('.ins .temp').html();
 $('.ins .temp').html("");
$('#t').html(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ins"> test test test <div class="temp">123</div></div>
<h2 id="t"></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing, just hide the `div`.

```
$(function(){
  $(".ins .temp").hide();
})
```

Comment: It is necessary that the div with the class "temp" was visible, and only the text "test" was cropped.

Answer (score 1):

You can easy achieve this with a simply `span` inside the div:

```js
$('.ins > span').text($('.ins > span').text().slice(0,5))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ins"><span> test test test </span><div class="temp">123</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing @void's code you can use

```
$(function(){
  $(".ins .temp").html("");
})
```

to remove the text from temp class and leave the div empty